# Example where optimal stopping does not exist

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I have a question about the optimal stop. Is it possible to give an example of the problem of optimal stopping on a Markov chain with a countable number of states and
discrete time in which the optimal stopping time does not exist?
It seems to me that such an example should exist, but I cannot invent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X_n$ be any Markov chain. Let the reward for stopping after $n$ steps be $1 - 1/n$.

Comment: Why there is no optimal stopping here? How can this be mathematically proved?

Comment: Your expected reward can be arbitrarily close to $1$, but can never be greater than or equal to $1$.  For any stopping time $T$, you can do better by taking $T+1$ instead.  So $T$ is not optimal.

Comment: Thanks, its realy easy :)

Comment: @RobertIsrael But reward function should depend on $X\small{n}$, not $n$, am I right?

Comment: @michaeluskov It depends on how you formulate the problem.  In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_stopping)'s formulation you have a sequence of reward functions $y_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, and there's nothing to prevent $y_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = 1 - 1/n$.  If you want a reward function that just depends on the current state, make $n$ part of the state.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks!